# Send an Array to an object constructor in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, audio

I'm trying to send values of an array created by checkboxes to the constructor of a "buzz" sound object. Code Follows.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="drums01" id="drums01" class="Checkbox" > Drums #1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="drums02" id="drums02" class="Checkbox"> Drums #2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="guitar01" id="guitar01" class="Checkbox"> Guitar #1</li>
//CHECKBOXES

<button class="button button_type_sound" id="b01">Play<q class="key" id="key_q">Q</q></button>
//BUTTON

var arr = new Array();

var drums01 = new buzz.sound("drumloop01", {
    formats: [ "wav" ],
    preload: true,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: true
});

var drums02 = new buzz.sound("drumloop02", {
    formats: [ "wav" ],
    preload: true,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: true
});

var guitar01 = new buzz.sound("guitarloop01", {
    formats: [ "wav" ],
    preload: true,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: true
});


//ATTEMPT TO CREATE SOUND OBJECT FROM ARRAY AND PLAY IT 
$("#b01").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var arr = new Array( $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).toArray());

    console.log(arr.toString());

    console.log("Try Playing Sound");
    console.log(arr.toString());

    var myGroup = new buzz.group(arr.toString());
myGroup.play();
});
```

Console Gives me the following error:

```
drums01,drums02 index.html:68
Try Playing Sound index.html:71
drums01,drums02 index.html:72
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle created fixing the code you posted in your question.
http://jsfiddle.net/fmKeV/3/

### Explanation

As you may see, in the "init section" I create an object literal of instances of buzz.sound.
Then, in the event handler of the button I map every selected checkbox to the corresponding sound (I changed the value of the input elements so that it is the same as the key in the buzzSounds object).
The `new Array` in `new Array($() ... .toArray())` in your code is not needed. The `toArray()` method called on the result of the `map` function is sufficient, otherwise the result would be a nested array, which is not what the buzz.group function needs.

### Code

#### Markup

```
<ul class="sounds">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="drumloop01" id="drums01" class="Checkbox" />Drums #1</li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="drumloop02" id="drums02" class="Checkbox" />Drums #2</li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="loops" value="guitarloop01" id="guitar01" class="Checkbox" />Guitar #1</li>
</ul>
<button class="button button_type_sound" id="b01">Play
    <q class="key" id="key_q">Q</q>
</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // init sounds
    var buzzSounds = {};

    buzzSounds.drumloop01 = new buzz.sound("drumloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    buzzSounds.drumloop02 = new buzz.sound("drumloop02", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    buzzSounds.guitarloop01 = new buzz.sound("guitarloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    //CLICK EVENT HANDLER
    $("#b01").on('click', function(e) {
        var sounds, group;

        //0) Prevent default
        e.preventDefault();

        //1) map every selected element to the sound defined in the "buzzSounds" object
        toPlay = $(".sounds input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
            return buzzSounds[this.value];
        }).toArray();

        //2) create a group from the collected buzz.sound instances
        myGroup = new buzz.group(toPlay);

        //3) play the group
        console.log("Try Playing Sounds", toPlay, myGroup);
        try {
            myGroup.play();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('uh-oh', e);
            //in this example the sound files have not been loaded, so an error could be raised
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var drums01 = new buzz.sound("drumloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    var drums02 = new buzz.sound("drumloop02", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    var guitar01 = new buzz.sound("guitarloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    //ATTEMPT TO CREATE SOUND OBJECT FROM ARRAY AND PLAY IT 
    $("#b01").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var arr = new Array();

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            arr.push($(this).val());
        });

        console.log(arr.toString());


        console.log("Try Playing Sound");
        console.log(arr.toString());

        var myGroup = new buzz.group(arr.toString());
        myGroup.play();

    });
});
```

Let me know how it works out.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4Wp/)

Comment: So much cleaner, thank you! However I'm still receiving an error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input " at line 72 (which is where my /script ends)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, to create a buzz.group we should pass the array no the string:

> Sounds can be added to a group by passing an array to the constructor.

but you pass string instead, so it should be like this:

```
var myGroup = new buzz.group([ 
    mySound1, 
    mySound2, 
    mySound3
]);
```

I changes your fiddle example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var drums = {};
    drums.drums01 = new buzz.sound("drumloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    drums.drums02 = new buzz.sound("drumloop02", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    drums.guitar01 = new buzz.sound("guitarloop01", {
        formats: ["wav"],
        preload: true,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: true
    });

    $("#b01").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var arr = new Array();

        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
            arr.push(drums[$(this).val()]);
        });

        var myGroup = new buzz.group(arr.toString());
        myGroup.play();
    });
});
```

check the new [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4Wp/4/) out.

**The Problem** in you have in your code is, you are passing the variable names as a string array, whereas you should pass the actual objects. to solve your problem you should make them accessible using a accessible in the context object like `var drums = {}` which you can use it in your anonymous function.

for mor information check this [link](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/group/) out.

Comment: Actually, I spent most of my night trying to make this work the way you suggest, but unfortunately I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined - is this a problem with the array values not passing?

Comment: @user3294635: check my answer again and get it done.

Comment: I'm 90% there! All that's changed now is that every value os passing to the array instead of just the checked boxes. Thanks again for your help, you've been a huge help!

Comment: Nevermind, I changed the final lines to "$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
            arr.push(loop[$(this).val()]);" and it works great, thanks!

Comment: @user3294635: you sould just use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` instead of `input[type="checkbox"]`. changed my answer again.

Comment: @user3294635: still waiting for your final feedback.